# Need to run tasks on several rails models. Can I use an array do loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rake task in which I operate on one model. It updates and deletes stuff in the table.
I have identical tables in other databases for which i created other models. How can I run the same tasks on those other models without duplicating code and keeping things DRY?

for example here is my code:

```
# Category is the model
new_region = Category.find_or_initialize_by_code(:code)
... 
...
new_region.save!
```

I want to be able to do the same thing with another model called `Hierarchy`
But I don't want to duplicate code like this:

```
# Hierarchy is the model
new_cat_region = Hierarchy.find_or_initialize_by_code(:code)
... 
...
new_cat_region_cat.save!
```

Is there a way I can create an array of models and loop through them like this?

```
   my_models = ['Category', 'Hierarchy']

   my_models.each do |model_name|
     a_region = model_name.find_or_initialize_by_code(:code)
       ... 
       ...
     a_region.save!
```

How would the strings in the array be treated? Should this be okay? I feel uncomfortable with the type casting that may be happening behind the scenes in rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, just use the class objects directly, like so:

```
my_models = [Category, Hierarchy]

my_models.each do |klass|
  a_region = klass.find_or_initialize_by_code(:code)
    ... 
    ...
  a_region.save!
end
```

Comment: Right, the `klass` variable is just a regular old variable, but it is storing a Class object as you iterate the array.  Imagine your array was a bunch of numbers - it would be the same deal.

Comment: BTW - the `klass` variable is commonly used because `class` is a reserved word.  Hence the spelling abuse.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as,

```
my_models = ['Category', 'Hierarchy']

my_models.each do |model_name|
 a_region = model_name.constantize.find_or_initialize_by_code(:code)
   ... 
   ...
 a_region.save!
```

constantize will convert string into class